# MS Lightswitch Application - How to change application language

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, localization, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using MS Lightswitch application with Silverlight client. I have to change the application to arabic interface, and I tried by change *Culture* in projects *General Properties* tab, and then loop through all the fields/properties in the screen and changed it display name as below:

```
iContentItem.DisplayName = "Something New Label In Arabic";
```

Where iContentItem is Microsoft.LightSwitch.Presentation.IContentItem. Here is the screen I have changed some labels.

[image: Sample Screen]

Note that in details table, field's labels are changed to Arabic, also in the top buttons bar, labels are changed. But in the left side menu doesn't affected, it is showing english labels, and also Grid's column headings are also in english. 
Can anybody suggest how to convert these labels to arabic.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried to change ApplicationCulture's value in the config file?
If you have changed but there are still some english texts on the UI then you can try this way:

1. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\LightSwitch\v5.0\Client folder`
2. Find folder which was named as similarly as Language code you want to use in your app. There is a file named `msls` in that folder. It contains default resource strings for UI language. You can replace string by yours.
3. Use developer tool of Browser to find resource file (resjson)

[image: Figure for 3rd option]

Comment: I have v3.0 installed on my machine, but in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\LightSwitch\v3.0\Client" folder, there is no msls file. It contains only 7 dll files

Comment: I guess you use a different version of Visual Studio so msls files do not be located there. This is a other way you should give a try: Use developer mode of browser to find a resjson file which is downloaded to client. You will have some information like: download url, file name... use those information to find resource file on application deployment folder.

Comment: Thanks @Linh, could you suggest me any link/article, how can I use developer mode of browser to find resjson file. I am using FireFox.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Take a look at figure image in my answer.

Comment: @Linh are you working with the Lightswitch HTML client? If so, it may be that its language behaviour/functionality is different to the Silverlight Desktop client that MIdrees is using.

Comment: Just want to provide information which can help him move on

Comment: I tried, Firefox > Options menu > Developer / Web Console > Network tab, but it is showing files like Client.xap, *.xml, screen files, but could not see the file you mentioned. Also I am using Silverlight Web Client not the desktop client.

Comment: I tried few ways to helping you but no one was sucessful. It seems resource strings is embbed in dll file. You should ask this question on Microsoft's forum. There is a guy named Huy Nguyen from Lightswitch team helped many LS developer in troubleshooting. If you are lucky, he can help you move on.

Comment: Yes let see. Thanks @Linh for your suggestions and showing another direction.